# Running aspnet_regsql.exe error

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-membership

When I try to run aspnet_regsql.exe on my database when I get to the Select the Server and Database screen and try to choose database the following error is displayed:

*Failed to query a list of database names from the SQL server. A network related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that the SQL server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)*

I have followed several tutorials, but nothing worked. Most just say to follow the installation wizard.

Answer (score 1):

Is your SQL Server instance definitely accessible over named pipes? By default, SQL Server is locked down quite tightly these days, so you may need to enable named pipes (or open up a firewall port if it's not on your local machine).

Network protocol changes are made using the [SQL Server Configuration Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

There's a good tutorial [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/).